# How to update Highchart from inside react a component?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am working with react 16.3 where `componentWillUpdate` is deprecated (strict mode). We have a react wrapper around `Highcharts` and used to update the `highchart` in `componentWillUpdate` that runs just before render.

But now in react 16.3 when the input `highchartoptions` prop updates, there seems to be no way to call `Highchart.update` before `render()` is called. Its suggested to use `componentDidUpdate` but its called only after `render()` and it doesn't seem to work at all.Any suggestions will help.

Code snippet here:

```js
export class HighchartReactWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // We maintain the user provided options being used by highchart as state
    // inorder to check if chart update is needed.
    this.state = { highChartOptions: this.props.options };
    this.onChartRendered = this.onChartRendered.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Create chart
    this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(this.container, this.state.highChartOptions, this.onChartRendered);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.options !== prevState.options) {
      return { highChartOptions: nextProps.options };
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.chart.update(this.state.highChartOptions, false, true); <---- Doesn't work
  }

  onChartRendered() {
    // Callbacks..
    if (this.props.onChartRenderedCallback !== undefined) {
      this.props.onChartRenderedCallback();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Destroy chart
    this.chart.destroy()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="react-highchart-wrapper">
        <div id={container => this.container = container} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

HighchartReactWrapper.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Chart options to be used in Highcharts library.
   */
  options: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onChartRenderedCallback: PropTypes.func
};

HighchartReactWrapper.defaultProps = {
  options: undefined,
  onChartRenderedCallback: undefined
};
```

Comment: What happens if you put `this.chart.update(this.state.highChartOptions, false, true);` as the last line in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: component didMount is only called once during initialization/creation phase. So subsequent update to option props doesn't update the chart.

Comment: Ashb, could you upload your work codes for this and how you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) which is called before the component rerender.

Comment: Thanks that was a good idea and i was able to call update on the chart there.